# Angular js is not rendering image tag inside svg element

Tags: angularjs, image, svg

I am trying to add an image inside inline svg using angular js dynamically. Please find the code below.

```
<svg id="deviceSelect" ng-if="$ctrl.src" class="device-mapper" width="100%" ng-attr-height="{{$ctrl.height + 20}}">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#f1f1f1"></rect>
    <g transform = "translate(10,10)">
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="" ng-attr-width="{{$ctrl.width}}" ng-attr-height="{{$ctrl.height}}" ng-href="{{ $ctrl.src }}"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Image is not loading until some event occurs in the page(like a button click). 
In the above code, $ctrl.src is loaded dynamically from an api.

Code to update image src:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('$ctrl.image', function (image) {
                        if (image) {
                            ctrl.src = _.find(image.links, {rel:'self'}).href;
                            ctrl.getImageMetaData(ctrl.src);
                        } else {
                            ctrl.src = null;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Should be `ng-src="{{ $ctrl.src }}"` instead of `ng-href="{{ $ctrl.src }}"`, is it?

Comment: either of those are not working

Comment: How are you calling your api, using $http or $.ajax?

Comment: I am using $http, does this makes any difference?

Comment: yup, in case of $.ajax, you gotta explicitly do a scope update/ $scope.$apply(); but $http handles it.

Comment: is it possible to upload the portion where api call is made as well?

Comment: Any further developments with this?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to match your scenario of loading the image from an api by giving some delay when setting the image on the controller's scope and to display it in an svg's image element by using a sample svg you can check the below code snippet, I hope it will be of help to you in order to solve your problem

```js
angular
  .module('demo', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  DefaultController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$sce'];
  
  function DefaultController($timeout, $sce) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.imgSrc = '';
    
    $timeout(getImage, 2000);
    
    function getImage() {
      var img = 'https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/news-images/new/news-events/images/l-nov/grass.jpg';
      var trustedImg = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(img);
      vm.imgSrc = trustedImg;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <svg width="500" height="250">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="circleView">
          <circle cx="250" cy="125" r="125" fill="#FFFFFF" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <image width="500" height="250" xlink:href="{{ctrl.imgSrc}}" clip-path="url(#circleView)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update:

With the above code in jsfiddle there is no error in the console window but with the same code running on node.js I see an error in the console first due to the AngularJS data binding expression `{{exp}}` in `xlink:href` attribute but the image loads after the getImage function gets called and when the `{{ctrl.imgSrc}}` expression gets resolved.

[image: The Project Folder and Code]
[image: The AngularJS App Running on Node.js]

In order to resolve the 404 error in the console one assumption that comes to my mind is that a directive could be created to in order to update the `xlink:href` attribute by writing jqLite or jQuery code in the `link` function.

Comment: This is perfectly working in my local, but once I deploy it to tomcat server it is not working(it's the same behavior with my code too). The image is not loading until some event occurs on the page like a button click.

Comment: Saiteja Y, I've ran the above code using node.js and the image loads, could you check my update once

Comment: Thanks alot, you saved my day. This is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, putting this in the app declaration:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="init()"></div>
```

Then init() will get fired on page load, then put this in the function being called:

```
// in controller

$scope.init = function () {
   $scope.$apply();
};
```

That should trigger the digest cycle. Let me know if it's ok?

Comment: I am updating $ctrl.src in $scope.watchCollection, so it is giving $digest already in progress error. I'll update the code in the question.